# Control characters problem (caret notation) with data.table::fread

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I try to read in a huge file line by line with fread in R:

```
fread(file=path,sep=NULL,header=F)
```

Fread stops with a warning on some lines, that are no problem for read_csv (from readr) or read.csv

An example (I don't think that the control characters will be displayed on stackoverflow):
`this is a problem`

If I view that with cat -A, it seems that the problematic characters are control characters in the beginning: `^E^C^?^C^B`

How to deal with that?

Is there a regex expression I could use to remove those? I tried something along the following lines, but I don't know if this will create other problems:

```
cat -A <FILE>| awk -F"$" '{gsub(/\^\?/,"",$0);print}'
```

EDIT: Screenshot: [image: control characters]

Comment: I think this would be one place where it would be appropriate to upload a screenshot of the problem characters. If it is control characters, then you can probably eliminate them using the regex `'[\x01-\x1A]+'`, which is the hex range for ^A-^Z

Comment: i added that screenshot
thank you for your suggestion, i will try that out

Comment: The characters are the hex codes for individual bytes. I would suggest sticking with `readr` . Use `read_file()` . It is meant for your use case (basically a character dump), and should be faster than `fread()`, which probably was not meant to be used that way.

Comment: i didn't know about read_file and it is useful and very fast. but i would still prefer to have the lines (each on is a facebook status update) to be read into a dataframe or similiar. the regex gives me "grep: Invalid range end".

Comment: i guess i will stick with `read_table` from `readr`, although i prefer `fread`, especially the possibility to pass shell commands as input